# Segmentation error with PyQt5 QMultimedia on Linux

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, pyqt5, gstreamer

I am using PyQt5 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I'm trying to play a .mp3 file using QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer. This is my code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class MyWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        media = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(sys.path[0] + '/sounds/banjo_A5_forte_normal.mp3')
        content = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(media)
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setMedia(content)
        self.player.play()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MyWidget()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But it gets SIGSEGV when I run it.

When I debug in PyCharm, set breakpoint to `self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()` and resume program, it works but gives warning:

```
(python:12491): GStreamer-WARNING **: 17:53:39.905: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvaapi.so': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvaapi.so: undefined symbol: gst_gl_display_egl_get_from_native

(python:12491): GStreamer-WARNING **: 17:53:40.030: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvaapi.so': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvaapi.so: undefined symbol: gst_gl_display_egl_get_from_native
```

Edit:
Command from comments. Can't just post 'mostly code'

Output from `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvaapi.so`:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc8f5b4000)
    libgstcodecparsers-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstcodecparsers-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1458a4b000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f145883a000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f145861c000)
    libva-drm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-drm.so.2 (0x00007f1458419000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f145820e000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f1458004000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f1457ccc000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f1457a40000)
    libva-x11.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-x11.so.2 (0x00007f145783a000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1457636000)
    libEGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1 (0x00007f1457422000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f145721e000)
    libva-wayland.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-wayland.so.2 (0x00007f1457019000)
    libva.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva.so.2 (0x00007f1456df8000)
    libwayland-client.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f1456be9000)
    libgstgl-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstgl-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1456983000)
    libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f145674b000)
    libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f14564b2000)
    libgstbase-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f145623d000)
    libgstallocators-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstallocators-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1456039000)
    libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1455cfe000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1455aaa000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1455793000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f14553f5000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f14551d6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1454de5000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1454bdd000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1458f6c000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f14549cb000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f14547a3000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f1454572000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f14542bc000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f14540b6000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f1453eae000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f1453cac000)
    libwayland-egl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f1453aaa000)
    libgbm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (0x00007f145389c000)
    libgudev-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgudev-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1453692000)
    libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f145341d000)
    libgsttag-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f14531e2000)
    liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007f1452f66000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f1452cf4000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f1452af0000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f14528ea000)
    libwayland-server.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-server.so.0 (0x00007f14526d7000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f14524a5000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f1452288000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f1452073000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command to enable the use of Qt MultiMedia in docker(ubuntu:18.04) so I guess it should also serve you.

```
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libgstreamer1.0-0 \
        gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
        gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
        gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \
        gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \
        gstreamer1.0-libav \
        gstreamer1.0-doc \
        gstreamer1.0-tools \
        libpulse-mainloop-glib0 \
        alsa-base \
        alsa-utils \
        pulseaudio
```

Comment: Have forgotten about this. apt says that gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad is broken. <Wanted to create a new line but posted>
Error message in Russian:
`Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Зависит: libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 (= 1.14.0-1ubuntu1) но 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 должен быть установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки: у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты.
`
Installed without -bad package, error is the same

Comment: @TimofeyX Have you tried removing that part of my command? Does it work if you remove that dependency? I tested it with docker a week ago and I didn't get that warning

Comment: Yes; I just accidentally sent not full comment, it's edited now

Comment: @TimofeyX I do not understand Russian for what you will have to translate, and your answer seems confusing, 1) Have you tried removing that part of my command?, 2) did my solution work for you?, 3) How have you installed pyqt5? 4) what is the output of `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvaapi.so`?

Comment: Yes, I removed the -bad part. Packages installed successfully, but my program gives the same error.

Comment: @TimofeyX Answer the enumerated questions I have asked you

Comment: @TimofeyX also see http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) No. 3) `sudo apt install pyqt5-dev-tools qtcreator && pip install PyQt5`

Comment: 4) doesn't fit. 49 lines

Comment: @TimofeyX Edit your question and add the 49 lines

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: @TimofeyX Try what http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/ points to install the plugin that you have trouble installing.

Comment: Ok, it's another broken packages error. I have something like `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : depends: libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 (= 1.14.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 must be installed`